# SQL Server - what permission need to open for view a table schema in a linked server

Tags: sql-server, permissions, linked-server

After creating a linked server on SSMS 2008, how should I see linked server table schema? Should I change any permission on remote SQL Server? Also, what commands can check those permissions for all accounts? Thanks.

EDIT: running on SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 1):

You specifically want to look at "sp_tables_ex" and "sp_columns_ex" if you are looking for table/column schema information.  You might also be able to use DMV on the remote server to pull the information you need.  The link below talks about the two SP mentioned above.

[KB203638](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/203638)

Comment: Sorry not to mention I am running a SQL Server 2000, and it doesn't have those system tables. What should I do?

Comment: both of the SP above should work in SQL Server 2000, here is a link to the documentation on sp_tables_ex, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176051.aspx

Comment: Thanks, even I find these info, still don't know what permission I need to grant for viewing table schema on linked server. Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the credentials used to connect to the linked server on the Security tab of the "New Linked Server" dialog, if you need to connect through using delegation or a specific logon, or you'll need to make changes to the permissions on the server being linked to.